# Creating a settings form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I have a very small project and I want to create a settings form. What is the best way to do this? Simply creating another Windows Form with checkboxes / textboxes and saving these settings using `Properties.Settings` class? It'll probably work but I'd like to have some input on what you think would be the best way to do this.

Comment: You should ask yourself what these settings are used for. For the current user of this same application?, Are settings for another application? Are these settings valid for the whole application whichever is the user? Are these settings applied  to every users in a lan environment using your application connected to a database?. Every question leads to a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually make a new form that holds all the controlls necessary to change whatever settings I have. I normally use the Properties.Settings class to hold my settings, but I sometimes use a SQLite database too. I guess it comes down to whatever is better suited. When using SQLite you also have to have some kind of wrapper that makes it easy to read/write your settings from/to the databse.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at SQLite but it's probably not needed for me.

Answer (score 1):

The way you suggest is a perfectly suitable approach.

Comment: Thanks, will use the way I suggested :-)